# How to add object array to new array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a sample array

```
const states = [{id:1,name:"New York",cities:[...]},{id:2,name:"California",cities:[...]}]
```

I want get all cities to an array in methods

```
...

const cities = []

this.states.forEach((state, index, array) => {
   this.cities = [...state.cities]
});

console.log(this.cities)
...
```

Result only get last cities (California), how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) like below.

```
this.cities = this.states.flatMap(s => s.cities);
```

Try below.

```js
const states = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "New York",
  cities: ['A', 'B']
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "California",
  cities: ['C', 'D']
}];
let cities = states.flatMap(s => s.cities);
console.log(cities);
```

---

Alternatively, using approach you use in your question. Your `cities` object was getting overwrite from each `states.cities`. You should be write it like below, so it will also include current `cities` values.

```
this.cities = [...this.cities, ...state.cities];
```

**Note :** Re-assigning value like above won't work with `const`. You need to declare `cities` with `let`. Or instead of re-assigning value, you can use `.push` like `this.cities.push(...state.cities);` which will work with `const` as well.

```js
const states = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "New York",
  cities: ['A', 'B']
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "California",
  cities: ['C', 'D']
}];

let cities = []
states.forEach((state, index, array) => {
  // Re-assigning value like below won't work with const. You need to declare cities with let.
  //cities = [...cities, ...state.cities];
  
  // .push will work with const and let
  cities.push(...state.cities);
});
console.log(cities);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning new cities value every time which eventually overrides previous value. In your `forEach` simply `push` new values.

```
this.cities.push(...state.cities)
```